# Unable to add an abbreviated IPv6 to a Cisco router

Tags: cisco-ios, ipv6, interface, gns3

I am very new to networking and playing around with GNS3. I am trying to configure a router to have 2 IPv6 addresses in a single interface (as far as I understood, this is possible with IPv6)

I managed to add the IPv6 address 2001:CAFE:DEA::25/64 with the following command

```
R1#enable
R1#config ter
R1(config)#ipv6 unicast-routing
R1(config)#int Ethernet0/0
R1(config-if)#ipv6 address 2001:CAFE:DEA::25/64
```

However, immediately afterwards, I try to add another, abbreviated IPv6 address `Fe80::1`
I just type the command (immediately after typing the last one above)

```
R1(config-if)#ipv6 address Fe80::1
```

but I get the error message

```
Incomplete command
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to configure a link-local address without the `link-local` keyword.

```
ipv6 address fe80::1 link-local
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the subnet mask.

Comment: The example routing table im looking at doesn't specify a subnet mask for that one though

Comment: You can always type a `?` to see what command is expected.